# Header file not found Error: <conio.h> and <process.h> while compiling in VScode Cmake or Clang++ in macOS Catalina

Tags: c++, c, macos, visual-studio-code, header

I've even installed VCpkg for missing Headers from Visual studio but doesn't seem to work.
After a bit of research I've found out

> unix based systems don't have "process" "conio" Headers

#### Is it safe to comment out these Headers ?

Will my program work fine ?

Comment: `conio.h` is a non standard C extension. If you comment out a header and it compiles without warnings it is fairly safe to say it isn't needed. But needing headers isn't related to which OS you are using.

Comment: _"unix based systems don't have Headers"_: huh??

Comment: Sorry markdown formatting <conio>

Comment: After the question edit it is not impossible for there to be a `conio` extension in *nix systems, if someone provides one. It's just not part of the standard C library.

Comment: This question is really confusing.. is it `VSCode` or `Visual Studio`? Why are you trying to use `conio` in a C++ program? `conio` is console io used in Borland C compilers, not Visual Studio C compilers, and the equivalent would probably be the `ncurses` library (I'm not sure).

Answer (score 0):

No, I would think that it is not safe to comment them out. If you comment them out you will have some functions in your code that are not defined, and your program won't compile. If you wrote the program I would recommend to look for some libraries that you can use in unix systems. Like ncurses instead of conio.